# Error inserting into SQLite Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, insert

```
public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME = "MY_DATABASE";
    public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "MY_TABLE";
    public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_CONTENT = "Content";
    public static final String DRINK_NAME = "Name";
    public static final String DRINK_CATEGORY = "Category";
    public static final String DRINK_COLOR = "Color";
    public static final String DRINK_TYPE = "Type";
    public static final String INGREDIENT_1="In1", INGREDIENT_2="In2", INGREDIENT_3="In3", INGREDIENT_4="In4", 
                               INGREDIENT_5="In5", INGREDIENT_6="In6";
    public static final String TIME_1="T1", TIME_2="T2", TIME_3="T3", TIME_4="T4", TIME_5="T5", TIME_6="T6";

    //create table MY_DATABASE (ID integer primary key, Content text not null);
    private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " ("
                    + DRINK_NAME + " TEXT, " + DRINK_CATEGORY + " TEXT, "
                    + DRINK_COLOR + " TEXT, " + DRINK_TYPE + " TEXT, "  
                    + INGREDIENT_1 + " TEXT, " + INGREDIENT_2 + " TEXT, " 
                    + INGREDIENT_3 + " TEXT, " + INGREDIENT_4 + " TEXT, " 
                    + INGREDIENT_5 + " TEXT, " + INGREDIENT_6 + " TEXT, "
                    + TIME_1 + " TEXT, " + TIME_2 + " TEXT, "
                    + TIME_3 + " TEXT, " + TIME_4 + "TEXT, " 
                    + TIME_5 + " TEXT);";
```

I keep getting the error "Table MYDATABASE_TABLE has no column named T4"
Clearly, I have a column named TIME_4, which is a variable name for "T4"

I then insert the values here:

```
public long insert(String name, String category, String color, String type, String ingredient1,
                        String ingredient2, String ingredient3, String ingredient4, String ingredient5,
                        String ingredient6, int time1, int time2, int time3, int time4, int time5){

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DRINK_NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(DRINK_CATEGORY, category);
        contentValues.put(DRINK_COLOR, color);
        contentValues.put(DRINK_TYPE, type);
        contentValues.put(INGREDIENT_1, ingredient1);
        contentValues.put(INGREDIENT_2, ingredient2);
        contentValues.put(INGREDIENT_3, ingredient3);
        contentValues.put(INGREDIENT_4, ingredient4);
        contentValues.put(INGREDIENT_5, ingredient5);
        contentValues.put(INGREDIENT_6, ingredient6);
        contentValues.put(TIME_1, time1);
        contentValues.put(TIME_2, time2);
        contentValues.put(TIME_3, time3);
        contentValues.put(TIME_4, time4);
        contentValues.put(TIME_5, time5);
        //  contentValues.put(TIME_6, time6);

        return sqLiteDatabase.insert(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm new to SQLite

Comment: "Clearly, I have a column named TIME_4, which is a variable name for "T4"" Nope, you clearly had a column named `"T4TEXT"`... :) It's the little things that get us.

Comment: ρяσѕρєя K already posted the answer, don't forget to increment `MYDATABASE_VERSION` to tell SQLite you have changed the schema.

Comment: Yup, that's what it was. Forgot to update the version. Thanks guys! Sometimes all you need is an extra set of eyes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
  + TIME_3 + " TEXT, " + TIME_4 + "TEXT, "
```

to

```
+ TIME_3 + " TEXT, " + TIME_4 + " TEXT, "
```

because you forget to place space between `TIME_4`  and `TEXT,`